# I am not able to intersect arrays. POST, PHP, How to intersect the POST array?

Tags: php, arrays, http-post, array-intersect

1) I am not able to intersect arrays:
2) I am not able to get values of associative POST array using a key

```
$adbcols=Array ( [tcid] => tcid .... array containing database column names

$aformval=Array ( ['tcbcheck'] => on ['tcprice'] => 100 ['tctitf'] => 01
```

.. array containing POST data

```
function amatchfnc($a, $b) {
    if ($a==$b){  return 0; }
    return ($a>$b) ? 1:-1; 
    } // function amatchfnc($a, $b)

foreach ($_POST as $apie=>$aformval  ) {

       $aresf=array_intersect_ukey($aformval,$adbcols,"amatchfnc");
} }
```

MORE FULL CODE:

```
foreach ($_POST as $apie=>$aformval  ) {
echo "<br><br> apie:"; print_r($apie);  
echo "<br><br> aformval:";  print_r($aformval);  //prints, also  aformval[tcbcheck]
echo "<br><br> aformval[tcbcheck]".$aformval['tcbcheck']; //gives empy line     

if(isset($_SESSION['vcurprcode'])) { $aformval['tcfkcode']=$_SESSION['vcurprcode'];} 
                               $aresf=array_intersect_ukey($aformval,$adbcols,"amatchfnc");

echo "<br><br><br> print_r(aresf)="; print_r($aresf);
                                            insertvalues($aresf,$adbcols, $conn, $vdbname, $tprice);
} //foreach ($_POST as $apie )
```

OUTPUT from prin_r, echo:

```
> apie:mon01
> 
> aformval:Array ( ['tcbcheck'] => on ['tcprice'] => 100 ['tctitf'] =>
> 01 ['tcdatefromto'] => priceFrom20140101To20140131 ['tcbset'] => 3
> ['tcbsettit'] => month ['tcdesc'] => )
> 
> aformval[tcbcheck]connectedstr02=SHOW COLUMNS FROM
> gintare_calendar.tapris3
> 0. ShowCol. Selected successfully gintare_calendar.tapris3
> 
> 
> print_r(adbcols)=Array ( [tcid] => tcid [tcdateacc] => tcdateacc
> [tcLdateacc] => tcLdateacc [tcdatecr] => tcdatecr [tcdesc] => tcdesc
> [tcbset] => tcbset [tcbsettit] => tcbsettit [tcbconf] => tcbconf
> [tcbcheck] => tcbcheck [tcdurup] => tcdurup [tcdurlow] => tcdurlow
> [tctitf] => tctitf [tcdate] => tcdate [tcdatefromto] => tcdatefromto
> [tccur] => tccur [tcbcur] => tcbcur [tcprice] => tcprice [tcbdisc] =>
> tcbdisc [tcfkdisc] => tcfkdisc [tcdisc] => tcdisc [tcdiscper] =>
> tcdiscper [tcpricedisc] => tcpricedisc [tcpurpose] => tcpurpose
> [tcdescpric] => tcdescpric [tcbsavset] => tcbsavset [tcprtit] =>
> tcprtit [tcfkcode] => tcfkcode [tcvauk] => tcvauk [tcdatefrom] =>
> tcdatefrom [tcdateto] => tcdateto [tcpryear] => tcpryear [tcprmonth]
> => tcprmonth [tcprweek] => tcprweek [tcprday] => tcprday )
> 
> 
> abefore intersect print_r(aformval)=Array ( ['tcbcheck'] => on
> ['tcprice'] => 100 ['tctitf'] => 01 ['tcdatefromto'] =>
> priceFrom20140101To20140131 ['tcbset'] => 3 ['tcbsettit'] => month
> ['tcdesc'] => [tcbcheck] => checked [tcfkcode] => 1 )
> 

> print_r(aresf)=Array ( [tcbcheck] => checked [tcfkcode] => 1 )
```

`$aresf` should contain all `$aformal` values.
I make intersection just to check if column names of aref coincides with column names of the database.  $adbcols i am getting from database schema.

THE HTML FILE which i POST contains the following paragraphs:

```
<input type= "text" name="mon01['tcprice']"  value="<?php echo $mon01['tcprice']; ?>"  " > 

<input type="range" name="mon01[range]" min="0" max="1000" >

<input type="hidden" class="mon" name="mon01['tctitf']"  value="01"; " size="1" >

<input type="hidden" class="mon" name="mon01['tcdatefromto']"  
value="priceFrom20140101To20140131"; " size="1" >

<input type="hidden" class="mon" name="mon01['tcbset']"  value="3"; " size="1" >

<input type="hidden" class="mon" name="mon01['tcbsettit']"  value="month"; " >

<textarea  cols="50" rows="3" name="mon01['tcdesc']" 
value="<?php echo $mon01['tcdesc'];  ?>" > </textarea>
```

GENERALLY array intersection works. The example below is with some arrays:

```
<?php
$af=array( "a"=>"a","c"=>"c", "e"=>"e" );
$ad=array( "a"=>"a","b"=>"b","c"=>"c","d"=>"d", "e"=>"e" );

$af=array_intersect_ukey($af,$ad,"amatchfnc");
    echo "<br> print_r(af)="; print_r($aresf);
?>
```

gives : print_r(aresf)=Array ( [a] => a [c] => c [e] => e )

**But if i try to intersect with POST array $aformval, i am getting strange results. How to intersect the POST array?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about your requirement, but i think this what you want. You can try `array_merge()`. Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. Since you `have same key` in both array the key=> value of second array will be in the resultant array(in this case `$aformval`)

```
$adbcols = array('tcid'=>'tcid','tcbcheck'=>'tcbcheck');
$aformval = array('tcprice'=>'100','tcbcheck'=>'on','tctitf'=>0,'tcid'=>1);
$arr = array_merge($adbcols,$aformval);
print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [tcid] => 1
    [tcbcheck] => on
    [tcprice] => 100
    [tctitf] => 0
)
```

If you need to check whether all `$aformaval keys` are present in `$adbcols` then try

```
$arr =array_diff(array_keys($aformval),array_keys($adbcols));
```

if `count($arr) > 0` then you have keys in `$aformval` that are not present in `$adbcols`. You can see the difference by print_r($arr);

Comment: I do not need to append values. I just want to check that $aformal keys corresponds to database column names. $adbcols contains database column names as keys and as values :) I get it from MySQL database schema.

Comment: Intersection does not work with POST array. It works if i write array by hand. Maybe there is some trick how post has to be handled?

Comment: Please read the answer above. The reason was that i was intersecting $aformval["'key'"] with $dbcols["key"]. The solution is to change html form.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge https://www.php.net/array_merge

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that  i was intersecting `$aformval["'key'"]` with `$dbcols["key"]`

OR i have to make html form without quates:

```
<input type= "text" name="mon01[tcprice]" value="<?php echo $mon01[tcprice]; ?>"   >
```

OR i have to add quates to adbcols keys, i.e. use $adbcols["'tcprice'"].

```
 <input type= "text" name="mon01['tcprice']" value="<?php echo $mon01['tcprice']; ?>"   >
```